# Translation Golf - Christmas Special Edition!

Tags: traducción, translation-golf

> The game is over! Check out the winners [here](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/23597/translation-golf-christmas-special-edition/23759#23759).

Welcome to Translation Golf's

## **Christmas Special Edition**!!!

The goal of the game is to translate the proposed text to Spanish using as few letters as possible.
If this is your first time playing, there's some info for beginners at the end of this post.

---

Para estas fechas señaladas, hemos pensado hacer una edición especial, con un texto más largo y más semanas para jugar con él :D

El texto elegido es el famosísimo poema *[A Visit from St. Nicholas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Visit_from_St._Nicholas)*, de autor desconocido*:

> 'Twas the night before Christmas, when all through the house
> Not a creature was stirring, not even a mouse.
> The stockings were hung by the chimney with care,
> In hopes that St Nicholas soon would be there.
>
> The children were nestled all snug in their beds,
> While visions of sugar-plums danced in their heads.
> And mamma in her ‘kerchief, and I in my cap,
> Had just settled our brains for a long winter’s nap.
>
> When out on the lawn there arose such a clatter,
> I sprang from the bed to see what was the matter.
> Away to the window I flew like a flash,
> Tore open the shutters and threw up the sash.
>
> The moon on the breast of the new-fallen snow
> Gave the lustre of mid-day to objects below.
> When, what to my wondering eyes should appear,
> But a miniature sleigh, and eight tiny reindeer.
>
> With a little old driver, so lively and quick,
> I knew in a moment it must be St Nick.
> More rapid than eagles his coursers they came,
> And he whistled, and shouted, and called them by name!
>
> "Now Dasher! now, Dancer! now, Prancer and Vixen!
> On, Comet! On, Cupid! on, on Donner and Blitzen!
> To the top of the porch! to the top of the wall!
> Now dash away! Dash away! Dash away all!"
>
> As dry leaves that before the wild hurricane fly,
> When they meet with an obstacle, mount to the sky.
> So up to the house-top the coursers they flew,
> With the sleigh full of Toys, and St Nicholas too.
>
> And then, in a twinkling, I heard on the roof
> The prancing and pawing of each little hoof.
> As I drew in my head, and was turning around,
> Down the chimney St Nicholas came with a bound.
>
> He was dressed all in fur, from his head to his foot,
> And his clothes were all tarnished with ashes and soot.
> A bundle of Toys he had flung on his back,
> And he looked like a peddler, just opening his pack.
>
> His eyes-how they twinkled! his dimples how merry!
> His cheeks were like roses, his nose like a cherry!
> His droll little mouth was drawn up like a bow,
> And the beard of his chin was as white as the snow.
>
> The stump of a pipe he held tight in his teeth,
> And the smoke it encircled his head like a wreath.
> He had a broad face and a little round belly,
> That shook when he laughed, like a bowlful of jelly!
>
> He was chubby and plump, a right jolly old elf,
> And I laughed when I saw him, in spite of myself!
> A wink of his eye and a twist of his head,
> Soon gave me to know I had nothing to dread.
>
> He spoke not a word, but went straight to his work,
> And filled all the stockings, then turned with a jerk.
> And laying his finger aside of his nose,
> And giving a nod, up the chimney he rose!
>
> He sprang to his sleigh, to his team gave a whistle,
> And away they all flew like the down of a thistle.
> But I heard him exclaim, ‘ere he drove out of sight,
> "Happy Christmas to all, and to all a good-night!"
>
> <sub>2085 letters</sub>

<sub>* El relato se publicó de manera anónima en 1823. [Clement Clarke Moore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clement_Clarke_Moore) se atribuyó la autoría en 1837. Hoy en día varios expertos piensan que en realidad el autor original era [Henry Livingston Jr.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henry_Livingston_Jr.), muerto en 1828.</sub>

Como traducción propia (¡hay que respetar las reglas!), enlazo a la [traducción al español tal cual me la ha dado Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/#en/es/%27Twas%20the%20night%20before%20Christmas%2C%20when%20all%20through%20the%20house%20%0ANot%20a%20creature%20was%20stirring%2C%20not%20even%20a%20mouse.%20%0AThe%20stockings%20were%20hung%20by%20the%20chimney%20with%20care%2C%20%0AIn%20hopes%20that%20St%20Nicholas%20soon%20would%20be%20there.%0A%0AThe%20children%20were%20nestled%20all%20snug%20in%20their%20beds%2C%20%0AWhile%20visions%20of%20sugar-plums%20danced%20in%20their%20heads.%20%0AAnd%20mamma%20in%20her%20%E2%80%98kerchief%2C%20and%20I%20in%20my%20cap%2C%20%0AHad%20just%20settled%20our%20brains%20for%20a%20long%20winter%E2%80%99s%20nap.%0A%0AWhen%20out%20on%20the%20lawn%20there%20arose%20such%20a%20clatter%2C%20%0AI%20sprang%20from%20the%20bed%20to%20see%20what%20was%20the%20matter.%20%0AAway%20to%20the%20window%20I%20flew%20like%20a%20flash%2C%20%0ATore%20open%20the%20shutters%20and%20threw%20up%20the%20sash.%0A%0AThe%20moon%20on%20the%20breast%20of%20the%20new-fallen%20snow%20%0AGave%20the%20lustre%20of%20mid-day%20to%20objects%20below.%20%0AWhen%2C%20what%20to%20my%20wondering%20eyes%20should%20appear%2C%20%0ABut%20a%20miniature%20sleigh%2C%20and%20eight%20tiny%20reindeer.%0A%0AWith%20a%20little%20old%20driver%2C%20so%20lively%20and%20quick%2C%20%0AI%20knew%20in%20a%20moment%20it%20must%20be%20St%20Nick.%20%0AMore%20rapid%20than%20eagles%20his%20coursers%20they%20came%2C%20%0AAnd%20he%20whistled%2C%20and%20shouted%2C%20and%20called%20them%20by%20name!%0A%0A%22Now%20Dasher!%20now%2C%20Dancer!%20now%2C%20Prancer%20and%20Vixen!%20%0AOn%2C%20Comet!%20On%2C%20Cupid!%20on%2C%20on%20Donner%20and%20Blitzen!%20%0ATo%20the%20top%20of%20the%20porch!%20to%20the%20top%20of%20the%20wall!%20%0ANow%20dash%20away!%20Dash%20away!%20Dash%20away%20all!%22%0A%0AAs%20dry%20leaves%20that%20before%20the%20wild%20hurricane%20fly%2C%20%0AWhen%20they%20meet%20with%20an%20obstacle%2C%20mount%20to%20the%20sky.%20%0ASo%20up%20to%20the%20house-top%20the%20coursers%20they%20flew%2C%20%0AWith%20the%20sleigh%20full%20of%20Toys%2C%20and%20St%20Nicholas%20too.%0A%0AAnd%20then%2C%20in%20a%20twinkling%2C%20I%20heard%20on%20the%20roof%20%0AThe%20prancing%20and%20pawing%20of%20each%20little%20hoof.%20%0AAs%20I%20drew%20in%20my%20head%2C%20and%20was%20turning%20around%2C%20%0ADown%20the%20chimney%20St%20Nicholas%20came%20with%20a%20bound.%0A%0AHe%20was%20dressed%20all%20in%20fur%2C%20from%20his%20head%20to%20his%20foot%2C%20%0AAnd%20his%20clothes%20were%20all%20tarnished%20with%20ashes%20and%20soot.%20%0AA%20bundle%20of%20Toys%20he%20had%20flung%20on%20his%20back%2C%20%0AAnd%20he%20looked%20like%20a%20peddler%2C%20just%20opening%20his%20pack.%0A%0AHis%20eyes-how%20they%20twinkled!%20his%20dimples%20how%20merry!%20%0AHis%20cheeks%20were%20like%20roses%2C%20his%20nose%20like%20a%20cherry!%20%0AHis%20droll%20little%20mouth%20was%20drawn%20up%20like%20a%20bow%2C%20%0AAnd%20the%20beard%20of%20his%20chin%20was%20as%20white%20as%20the%20snow.%0A%0AThe%20stump%20of%20a%20pipe%20he%20held%20tight%20in%20his%20teeth%2C%20%0AAnd%20the%20smoke%20it%20encircled%20his%20head%20like%20a%20wreath.%20%0AHe%20had%20a%20broad%20face%20and%20a%20little%20round%20belly%2C%20%0AThat%20shook%20when%20he%20laughed%2C%20like%20a%20bowlful%20of%20jelly!%0A%0AHe%20was%20chubby%20and%20plump%2C%20a%20right%20jolly%20old%20elf%2C%20%0AAnd%20I%20laughed%20when%20I%20saw%20him%2C%20in%20spite%20of%20myself!%20%0AA%20wink%20of%20his%20eye%20and%20a%20twist%20of%20his%20head%2C%20%0ASoon%20gave%20me%20to%20know%20I%20had%20nothing%20to%20dread.%0A%0AHe%20spoke%20not%20a%20word%2C%20but%20went%20straight%20to%20his%20work%2C%20%0AAnd%20filled%20all%20the%20stockings%2C%20then%20turned%20with%20a%20jerk.%20%0AAnd%20laying%20his%20finger%20aside%20of%20his%20nose%2C%20%0AAnd%20giving%20a%20nod%2C%20up%20the%20chimney%20he%20rose!%0A%0AHe%20sprang%20to%20his%20sleigh%2C%20to%20his%20team%20gave%20a%20whistle%2C%20%0AAnd%20away%20they%20all%20flew%20like%20the%20down%20of%20a%20thistle.%20%0ABut%20I%20heard%20him%20exclaim%2C%20%E2%80%98ere%20he%20drove%20out%20of%20sight%2C%20%0A%22Happy%20Christmas%20to%20all%2C%20and%20to%20all%20a%20good-night!%22), que se queda en 2246 letras. Apenas la he mirado por encima, así que no sé si estará bien. No la incluyo aquí porque con el tag de *spoiler* sale un recuadro vacío enorme y no tiene mucho sentido :D

---

**This is a Special Edition and, as such, there are some special rules ^_^**

The **TL;DR** is that there's a Prose category and a Rhyme category; the winning answer in each category will get a bounty; and you can participate in both categories if you want!

For the complete set of rules, check out the following links.

- **Special Edition rules**: [Translation-Golf Christmas Special Edition 2017 rules](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2756/13628)
- General rules: [Translation-Golf rules](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2592/5481)

Also, remember that symbols other than letters and numbers do not count towards the total length. You can use this link to check the length of your answer:

- Letter counter: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2ermv0rh/2/embedded/result/)

You may want to check past [translation-golf](/questions/tagged/translation-golf) questions to get a feel of the game dynamics and the kind of answers expected.

Want to share translation ideas, ask for clarifications or just tease other contesters? Join us in [Translation-Golf!](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66153/translation-golf), our game-specific chat room, or in [La Tertulia](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46061/la-tertulia), Spanish.SE's official chat room!

### Have a lot of fun, Happy Holidays and a Merry Christmas!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Christmas Special Edition Winners

#### Category: Prose

- Title of "**Manco de Lepanto**" and +50 rep bounty awarded to: [**VeAqui** (838 letters)](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/23597/translation-golf-christmas-special-edition/23688#23688)

#### Category: Rhyme

- Title of "**Naricísimo Infinito**" and +50 rep bounty awarded to: [**walen** (1372 letters after bonus)](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/23597/translation-golf-christmas-special-edition/23680#23680)

Answer (score 4):

#### Rhyme - 1614

> Era Nochebuena, y en toda la casa
>   ni un alma movíase, no, ni una rata.
>   Calcetas con mimo ya sobre el hogar
>   porque Papá Noël estaba al llegar.
>
> Acurrucados los críos en sus camas,
>   con algodones de äzúcar soñaban.
>   Con mi gorro yo, mamá con su pañuelo,
>   ya listos para echar un sueño de invierno.
>
> Cuando del jardín un gran ruido llegó,
>   salí de la cama y fui a ver qué pasó.
>   Salté como un rayo hacia la ventana,
>   abrí el postigo, subí la persiana.
>
> De nieve reciente en el seno la luna
>   le daba a las cosas claridad diurna.
>   Pasmados mis ojos, ¿qué fue lo que vieron?
>   Ocho renitos y un mini trineo.
>
> Vivaracho y pronto su viejo chofer,
>   al momento vi que era Papá Noël.
>   Cual águilas raudas sus renos llegaban,
>   y a silbos y a voces ¡a todos llamaba!
>
> "¡Ya Dasher! ¡Ya, Dancer! ¡Ya, Prancer y Vixen!
>   ¡Va, Comet! ¡Va, Cupid! ¡Va, Donner y Blitzen!
>   ¡Subíos al porche! ¡Subíos al muro!
>   ¡Aprisa! ¡Aprisa! ¡Corred todos juntos!"
>
> Cual hojas que el viento furioso levanta
>   cuando hallan un tope y al cielo las alza.
>   Volaron los corceles hasta el tejado,
>   con Claus, y el trineo de juegos cargado.
>
> Y en un parpadeo yo pude escuchar
>   a cada pezuña trotar y pisar.
>   Y al tiempo que yo de asomarme dejaba,
>   por la chimenea con su hato bajaba.
>
> De pies a cabeza con pieles vestido,
>   ropaje de hollín y ceniza teñido.
>   Su espalda cargada con muchos juguetes,
>   parecía un mendigo, abriendo paquetes.
>
> ¡Oh, el brillo en sus ojos! ¡Hoyuelo feliz!
>   ¡Rosadas mejillas, cereza nariz!
>   Su boca graciosa cual arco curvada,
>   nívea en su barbilla su barba poblada.
>
> Sujeta una pipa tenía en sus dientes,
>   su humo, guirnalda, rodeaba su frente.
>   Tenía ancha cara y redonda barriga,
>   que al reír ¡agitaba como gelatina!
>
> Viejo y fofo duende, gordito feliz,
>   sin querer, al verle, ¡echéme a reír!
>   Giró su cabeza y un ojo guiñó,
>   y entonces el miedo desapareció.
>
> Siguió trabajando sin decir ni pío,
>   las medias llenó y de repente dio un giro.
>   Tocó su nariz y movió su cabeza,
>   ¡y arriba que se fue, por la chimenea!
>
> A su equipo silbó, saltó a su trineo,
>   cual pelo de cardo volando se fueron.
>   Mientras se perdía, se le oía gritar:
>   "¡Buena noche a todos! ¡Feliz Navidad!"

56 versos dodecasílabos en 14 estrofas, cada una con su rima AABB asonante.

Comment: ¡Muy bueno! Yo todo contento porque casi he conseguido rimar todos los versos y la mayoría con las mismas sílabas y veo esto y me da vergüenza mi poema que parece que lo ha escrito un robot borracho.

Answer (score 2):

Prose (meanwhile...)

## 838 char

> En Nochebuena, la casa quieta, sola, medias en la chimenea listas para Papa Noel. Los chicos en cama con dulces sueños, mamá con su pañuelo y con mi gorra listos a ivernar.
>   Oí algo afuera, me baje de cama a ver,
>   La luna brillaba cual sol, mostrando un trineito con 8 renos.
>   Un viejo y vivaz piloto, deduje 'Papá Noel', iba cual rayo, diciendo a sus renos:
>   "Dasher, Dancer, Prancer, Vixen, Comet, Cupid, Donner y Blitzen, al atrio";
>   Al soco, evitando trabas subiendo, y llegaron a casa con el saco lleno de juguetes y Papa Noel.
>   Se oyó en el techo los pasos de los renos y en mi mente lo vi bajar por la chimenea;
>   Cubierto todo de pieles, con cenizas, cargando el saco de jugetes y abriendo su paquete;
>   Guiñó sus ojos, sonrisa feliz, cachetes cual rosas, nariz de cereza, boca arqueada y barba blanca brillante;
>   Tenía la pipa con los dientes, humo rodeando su cabeza, cara ancha, y una panza que brincó mientras reía;
>   Callado, a lo suyo, llenó medias, se despidió y trepó por la chimenea;
>   Saltó al trineo, silbó, se alejó y antes de perderse le oí "Feliz Navidad y buenas noches a todos"

Cualquier duda, con la Asale en las entradas Co (Colombia), comentarios o por el chat. En particular "al soco" es ir rápido y los múltiples ';' son para dividir estrofas